# CheckBox with Comma Separated string values

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

i'm new to asp.net mvc and i'm trying to handle saving and retrieving the checkBox checked values.

In my view i'm having below checkboxes

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cabling in coduit" name="Prepration" value="cabling in coduit"/>cabling in coduit<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="Power to be done by liteStart" name="Prepration" value="Power to be done by liteStart"/>Power to be done by liteStart<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="Other - pls spec" name="Prepration" value="Other - pls spec"/>Other - pls spec<br />
```

In my controller:

```
String vals=Request.Form["Prepration"];
```

I get the checked values as a comma separated string and i save that string into my database column.

Now when i retrieve the value i have something like below.

> cabling in coduit,Power to be done by liteStart

How can i check the relevant checkboxes on my edit view using the comma separated string

Answer (score 0):

then you can do something like this

```
    if(vals.indexOf("cabling in coduit") > -1 ){
       $('#cabling in coduit').prop('checked', true);
    }
    else if(vals.indexOf("Power to be done by liteStart") > -1 ){
       $('#Power to be done by liteStart').prop('checked', true);
    }
    else if(vals.indexOf("Other - pls spec") > -1 ){
       $('#Other - pls spec').prop('checked', true);
    }
```

Comment: The code supplied is javascript, and the lines that start with $ use jQuery. You would put this code in the $(document).ready() function and it would restore the checkbox state for you. You could read more about jQuery to get the idea.